# C - format String to array

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

```
char str1 [] =
    "{ \'Carl Maria von Weber\', \'weber\', 8 }{ \' Maria  von   Carl Weber \', \'weber\', 1 }\n"
    "{ \'Carl Weber Maria von\', \'weber\', 2 }\n"
    "{ \'Carl-Maria von Weber\', \'weber\', 4 }\n"
    "{ \'Chuck Norris\', \'norrischuck\', 100 }";
```

If I have such a string, how can I store it in the field, so I should

```
char field [0] = Carl Maria von Weber
char field [1] = weber
char field [2] = 8
```

I created the following code, which also stores {}, characters in the field. Can I edit the string str before using the function so that the characters {},? are removed. Or am I wrong about this and do you know any other procedure?

```
char *src;  
char a[2000];
src=a;

fscanf(fp,"%[^\"]",src);
//printf("%s\n",src);

int count=1000;
char output[1000][1000];    
int i = 0;
while (i < count) {
    const char *start;
    int len;
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
        src++;
    if (*src == '\0')
        break;
    if (*src == '\'') {
        start = ++src;
        len = strcspn(src, "\'");
        src += len;
        if (*src == '\'')
            src++;
    } else
    if (*src == '\"') {
        start = ++src;
        len = strcspn(src, "\"");
        src += len;
        if (*src == '\"')
            src++;
    } else {
        start = src;
        len = strcspn(src, " \t\f\v\r\n");
        src += len;
    }
    snprintf(output[i], sizeof(output[i]), "%.*s", len, start);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: 4 questions from [aaron18](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15140510/aaron18) and 2 similar from [aaron9999](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15144992/aaron9999) on a similar task.  Maybe the 2 of you should exchange  notes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question didn't contain any requirments for the string, I'm assuming that

- record format is `{ \'name1\', \'name2\', value }` (all spaces between parts are important)
- first field is at most 100 characters and can contain only alphabet characters, spaces or `-`
- second field is at most 100 characters and can contain only alphabet characters or spaces
- third field is a digit.

From your example code I'm assuming also there are at most 1000 records. This code parses and prints your example string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct parsedStruct
{
  char name1[100];   // Carl Maria von Weber
  char name2[100];   // weber
  int value;         // 8
};

int main (void)
{
  char str1[] =
    "{ \'Carl Maria von Weber\', \'weber\', 8 }{ \' Maria  von   Carl Weber \', \'weber\', 1 }\n"
    "{ \'Carl Weber Maria von\', \'weber\', 2 }\n"
    "{ \'Carl-Maria von Weber\', \'weber\', 4 }\n"
    "{ \'Chuck Norris\', \'norrischuck\', 100 }";

  FILE *fp = fmemopen(str1, sizeof(str1), "r");
  if (fp)
  {
    struct parsedStruct output[1000];
    int numMatched, i = 0;
    do
    {
      numMatched = fscanf(fp, "{ \'%100[-a-zA-Z ]\', \'%100[a-zA-Z ]\', %d }", output[i].name1, output[i].name2, &output[i].value);
      if (feof(fp) || ferror(fp))
        break;
      if (numMatched == 3)
        ++i;
      else
        fgetc(fp);
    } while (i < sizeof(output) / sizeof(output[0]));

    fclose(fp);

    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      printf("%s, %s, %d\n", output[j].name1, output[j].name2, output[j].value);
  }
}
```